# How to use the user object in Facebook dialog using Facebook javascript SDK?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I want have feed dialog in which i also want to use his First name or user object.I'm using FB.Ui method.

```
    <script>
var publish = {
  method: 'stream.publish',
  display: 'popup', // force popup mode
  attachment: {
    name: 'I visted this Appp',
    caption: 'The Facebook Connect JavaScript SDK',
    description: (
      'A small JavaScript library that allows you to harness ' +
      'the power of Facebook, bringing the user\'s identity, ' +
      'social graph and distribution power to your site.'
    ),
    href: 'http://fbrell.com/'
  }
};

FB.ui(publish, Log.info.bind('stream.publish callback'));
</script>
```

As you can see in caption it is ' i visited this app'.I want to change it to the Facebook user's first name..i.e 'first_name visted this app'..Anyone can help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get info about the user, you would first need to have them authenticate with your application (no extended permissions would be needed as name is considered "basic" information).  Then you could then call a FQL query with the javascript api to get their name and then use that to populate the message.

**Authenticate user:**

```
<fb:login-button autologoutlink="true"></fb:login-button>
```

**Get users name:**

```
FB.api(
    {
      method: 'fql.query',
      query: 'SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid='+FB.getSession().uid
    },
    function(response) {
          alert(response[0].name);
    }
  );
```